# Pass a Python dict to a Java map possibly with JSON?

Tags: java, python, json, dictionary

I am calling a Java file within Python code. Currently, I am passing it several parameters which Java sees in its String[] args array. I would prefer to pass just one parameter that is a Python dictionary (dict) which Java can understand and make into a map. I know I will probably have to pass the python dictionary as a string.

How can I do this? Should I use JSON?

Comment: JSON, YAML, or even XML are good solutions to this problem. Alternatively, you may want to look into [jython](http://jython.org), which allows maps to be read as dicts and vice versa.

Comment: If you use Json, there are heaps of Json libs available. json-simple https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ or google Gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ are 2 options.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as JSON, and parse the info out of the JSON in Java.

If the data is more simple, you could make every other String in Java's String[] args parameter represent a key or value, and then have your code loop through those and add them to a map.

Comment: How do I go about converting the dict to a JSON and parsing the JSON in Java?

Comment: Converting the dictionary to JSON automatically may be possible with some libraries you may find, otherwise you'd have to generate it by stepping through the dictionary yourself. Passing the JSON to Java could be done in a few ways. You could quote the entire JSON text, and escape other quotes for your platform as you exec your Java process so the entire piece of JSON data is passed, but that's kind of hacky, and may not work if there's limited size of arguments for your OS or something. A better way perhaps is to dump the JSON to a temp file and pass the location to the temp file.

Comment: One other method is if you are okay with having the Java process always running, you could create a socket connection between your Python process and the Java one, and pass the JSON through that socket connection. This to me is the least hacky solution that I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a good choice. 
You could also use pickle on python side and http://www.roman10.net/loading-python-pickle-files-from-java/ on another